# Does Arcgis World Traffic Service Support History Data?

Tags: arcgis, traffic, esri-leaflet

Now, I use Esri Leaflet http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/premium-content.html

I want to Access Arcgis World Traffic Service History data,

Because, I only got a live traffic data.

May I access one month ago traffic data or another days?

I want to play the 3 days or 7 days change, that why I need to access history data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I access one month ago traffic data or another days?

yes. ArcGIS World Traffic is a time-enabled service, which means it supports passing any Epoch timestamp ([in milliseconds](https://www.epochconverter.com/)) as the [`time`](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/export-map.htm) request parameter.

[https://traffic.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Traffic/MapServer/export?...time=1526022000000](https://traffic.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Traffic/MapServer/export?bbox=-13169574.991485156%2C4040632.701303777%2C-13151287.432467928%2C4031078.0727681275&size=957%2C500&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=true&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&token=[yourtoken]&f=image&time=1526022000000)

in Esri Leaflet, you can either use the `to` and `from` constructor options ([live demo](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/visualizing-time-on-dynamic-map-layer.html)) or [`setTimeRange()`](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html#methods).

Comment: that's awesome and helpful.